# Laravel Observer not triggered on UpdateorCreate

Tags: laravel, observers

I have Model Model1 where I want to update a particular column rank on saved.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::saved(function ($model) {
         $service = new  Service();
         $service->updateRank($model->id);
    });
}
```

I put a log inside the saved. but it is not called

Comment: Are you sure the update in question doesn't happen to be re-applying data that's already there? If it is, Eloquent will ignore it and not fire the 'saved' event. Check out `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save()`. The `finishAndSave()` call is what's responsible for firing the event, but that won't happen if the `$saved` flag isn't `true`.

Answer (score -1):

You should use method `booted`.

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::saved(function ($model) {
        $service = new  Service();
        $service->updateRank($model->id);
    });
}
```